# Why doesn't this pointer passing work?

Tags: c

EDIT: An initial "float** floats;" was a typo, corrected. Also, "*floats[0] = 1.0;" does work, but "*floats[1] = 1.0;" segfauls at that point. The array is malloced. Compilation has no warnings on pedantic c99.

This worked:

(pseudo:)

```
void func(int*);
int i;
func(&i);
void func(int* i) {
 func2(i);
}
void func2(int* i) {
 *i = 2;
}
```

initial value changed to 2.

but this didn't work:

```
void func(float**);
float* floats;
func(&floats);
void func(float** floats) {
 func2(floats);
}
void func2(float** floats) {
 *floats[1] = 1.0;
}
```

segfault on assignment;

Comment: What kind of compiler lets you compile this without an error?

Comment: We are stabbing in the dark here until you post the actual code.  What is up here does not compile, and has plenty of typos (`floats **floats`).  If you can duplicate your error in an actual compiling test program, that would be a great help.

Comment: If you have fixed your typo, your current code still needs to allocate some memory for *\*floats* first before you assign a value to *\*floats[1]*. *floats* is a pointer to *float\**, *\*floats* is the pointer that points an array of float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you passing a pointer to an array?  Have you tried

```
func(float *floats)
{
  func2(floats);
}

func2(float *floats)
{
  floats[0] = 2;
}
```

Comment: Not the issue; the point is to manipulate external to the functions variables.

Comment: I understand, but arrays are passed as pointers, you don't pass a pointer to a pointer for an array unless you intend to change the address of the allocated memory.  Try my solution and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

because 'floats' is a bad pointer.  Sure, you declared the pointer, but you haven't allocated any memory, so wherever it happens to point will be invalid.

Also, the address of a float** is a float***, which is not what your function calls for.

Comment: Dude, post your real code. Don't make people waste time debugging transcription errors and omissions.

Comment: What are you talking about?  If you can't understand something as simple as what I said above then maybe you should start with a beginner's tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have these 2 funcs, like you posted:

```
void func2(float** floats) {
 *floats[1] = 1.0;
}
void func(float** floats) {
 func2(floats);
}
```

Then you have the following code:

```
float* floats;
func(&floats);
```

What happens? First, `floats` is a `float *`, and since it's not assigned, it points to a random memory location, say `0xBADD`. If you write to here, you're liable to screw something up.

The address of `floats`, `&floats` is another memory location pointing to where it is on the stack, say `0x1000`. This is passed to `func`, which is then verbatim passed to `func2`.

What does `func2` do? It tries to write something in the location `*floats[1]`. I'm not sure what happens first, the bracket or the star, so let's take both cases:

`*(floats[1])`: First you find what `floats[1]` is. Since `floats` is the memory location of the initial `floats` variable, this is `0x1000`. `floats[1]` would be `0x1004`, since pointers are 4 bytes wide assuming a 32-bit system. Then you try to dereference this pointer, which is the value of whatever is in memory location `0x1004`. This could be anything, like `0xBAD2`, so trying to write a float value there most likely causes a segfault.

`(*floats)[1]`. Here you first dereference `floats`, which gets you `0xBADD`, of type `float *`. You then try to write a value into `0xBADD + 4`, or `0xBAE1`. This is memory that hasn't been allocated for you, so writing there will likely cause a segfault.

Either way, you're messing with memory that isn't yours, thus leading to a segfault.

Comment: oh.. well say `float *floats = ...;` or something! in that case you would want `(*floats)[1]`, or just pass the array directly like in the accepted answer.